# React + Redux: "<Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm getting this error:

> `<Provider>` does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

I have a component with this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  NativeAppEventEmitter
} from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Onboarding from "./src/onboarding/Onboarding";
import Home from "./src/home/Home";
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';

class Edmund extends Component {

  ...

  startScreen() {
    if (this.state.screen === "HOME" ) {
      return (<Home />);
    }

    return (
      <Onboarding />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={ createStore(reducers) }>
        { this.startScreen() }
      </Provider>
    )
  }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Edmund', () => Edmund)
```

My `src/reducers/index.js` file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
  libraries: () => []
});
```

My packages:

```
{
  "name": "Indigo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^15.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-apple-pay": "0.0.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.11.0-beta",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-paged-scroll-view": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "latest",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "latest"
  }
}
```

I'm not even doing anything fancy so I don't get why there's this error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you dig into the react-redux code a bit you see this

```
if (store !== nextStore) {
  warnAboutReceivingStore()
}
```

So it would seem all you would have to do is move the createStore call outside.

```
store = createStore(reducers)


class Edmund extends Component {

  ...

  startScreen() {
    if (this.state.screen === "HOME" ) {
      return (<Home />);
    }

    return (
      <Onboarding />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={ store }>
        { this.startScreen() }
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

Haven't tested it but should work.

Comment: Dan Abramov explained this in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/259).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and the workaround is to remove the DevTools.

```
<Provider store={store} >
   <App />
</Provider>
```

In the component App's render() method, there is a:

```
<DevTools />
```

After I removed the DevTools, the error disappeared.

This is not a good solution, just for your reference.